# RANDBETWEEN but smaller than another cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, random-number-generator

I would like to generate a number that is random but smaller than the cell above (I'm doing 4th grade subtraction worksheet).

What is the formula for this?

I tried `=randbetween(C3, 99)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it smaller then the one above it should go in the other space:

```
=randbetween(1,C3-1)
```